# Picture Group set to Range

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies another noob question.  I have been tasked with writing a document within excel, the front cover has a lot of images on it and i have grouped these images together.  As there is a risk that the user could move this group. I want to set it so each time that sheet is selected it moves back to its original location.  I have looked over the web and i can't seem to find anything for a group of images.

I have tried this and it doesnt work at all. :(

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim PicGroup As GroupShapes


With Range("A1")
    PicGroup.Name = "HeaderGrp"
    PicGroup.Visible = True
    PicGroup.Top = .Top
    PicGroup.Left = .Left
End With
End Sub
```

So my group of images I have called `HeaderGrp` I have put this on Activate Worksheet in VBA and i want this to always move or fix to cells A1.

I would also love this to fit to the page width and length if anyone knows how to do that.

Snapshot of what i would like: - 
1) on sheet selection, image group moves to the correct location.
2) image group auto adjusts to page width and height.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You never set your `PicGroup` Variable, you need to set it after it's declaration, then your code will work.

Comment: Hi @Damian i have tried adding `Set PicGroup = "HeaderGrp"` after and it says type mismatch, any suggestions.  Apologies i am still new and learning.

Comment: Are all your images are grouped?

Comment: Yes all images are currently grouped but when i get further there will be images that are not in the group.  This group is only the front page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me. Pictures appear to be treated as a type of `Shape`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim p As Shape

With activesheet
    Set p = .Shapes("Pics") 'name
    p.Top = .Range("a1").Top
    p.Left = .Range("a1").Left
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @SJR i tried this only changing "Pics" to "HeaderGrp" and i get this error = `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method` any ideas? Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Is that the name given to the grouped pictures? Check the box at top left of the sheet.

Comment: Also I see I put it in the wrong event so make you remove the ` Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: Hi @SJR yes my group name is "HeaderGrp" and i can confirm that now works!! AMAZING!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should get your grouped images:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim PicGroup As GroupShapes

    'loop through all your shapes
    For Each shp In Me.Shapes
        'if the shape is grouped then
        'set your PicGroup variable
        'and exit the loop
        If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
            Set PicGroup = shp.GroupItems
            Exit For
        End If
    Next shp

    With Range("A1")
        PicGroup.Name = "HeaderGrp"
        PicGroup.Visible = True
        PicGroup.Top = .Top
        PicGroup.Left = .Left
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Damian this gets to `PicGroup.Name = "HeaderGrp"` and then does this error `run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.  Any idea what this means? Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Hi Damian i deleted all my code and replaced it with yours, i cant see where else it knows to get the name from if it is not there? Apologies i am very new to all this.

Comment: Well as you told, you only have 1 grouped  block of images, so if there is any, it will be that one.

Comment: Hi Damian, i deleted the `PicGroup.Name = "HeaderGrp"` i then get the same error on the next line down.  Apologies. :-(

Comment: Thing is, as I've just read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.groupshapes)  `GroupShapes` object doesn't have `.Top` or `.Left` properties. You can't move a `GroupShapes`

Comment: Aaah okay.  Thank you Damian. I will try and ungroup them and see if i can set them by picture individually. Thank you for your help.